# time dtype in numba-Using time attribute in Numba jitclass spec/ signature

Tags: python-3.x, time, jit, numba, specs

I am using Numba, jitclass to improve my execution time.
I am trying to spec time dtype in myClass with jitclass decorator.
I tried time, datetime, string, float64/32, numba.NPDattime etc but getting errors. Couldnt find anything in documentation.
My code is....

```
spec = [ ('currtm',datetime.time)]

@jitclass(spec)
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self): #
        
        self.currtm = time.time()
```

to put it simply, I need a numba data type for the the python 'time' or 'datetime' return value. I checked ans time method returns float but numba isnt friendly with that.
The error I am getting says
"TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got <method 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>"

The problem is, Numba type instance for time cant be seen in their documentation ? In old version there is some hints but it seems they have been deprecated it.
Any idea how to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checked and its not supported yet by Numba. so I have to use objemode or ctypes
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4003